# Bits required to address registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, machine-code

Say I have 12 registers. How many bits must be reserved in the machine code instruction order to address any of these 12 registers?

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far? What's unclear / where are you stuck?

Comment: My initial thought is that it will require 8 bits - one byte to store a hex number (since the number of registers is less than 16)

Comment: What do you mean by "hex number" and why does it take one byte to store it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question to be honest.

Comment: OK, you used the term "hex number". That is not a thing. ("Hex" is a serialization format, a certain way to convert a number to text form.) Since presumably you must have meant something when you wrote that, I'm asking you what you mean by "hex number".

Comment: Well registers store 4 digit base 16 numbers, so I thought that to address one, it would use the same.

Comment: Are you talking about 16-bit registers? They can store numbers in the range 0 .. 65535, which written down in hex format takes 4 digits. I don't follow the "*to address one, it would use the same*" part.

Comment: You need 12 different states for the processor to react twelve times differently. Take a calculator, enter 12 and let it convert it to binary. It shows you a binary number hopefully without leading zeros. Count the number of binary digits and you know how many bits you need.

Answer (score 2):

It takes `ceil(log2(12))` bits to encode 1 of 12 possibilities in a normal fixed-width field.

But does having fewer than a power of 2 registers let us save any bits in an instruction with multiple register operands?  Yes, in this case.

A 3-register instruction has `12^3 = 1728` possible permutations of registers.  But using 3 separate 4-bit fields would give us `2^(4*3) = 4096` possible encodings.  So there's 1 redundant bit, because `2^11 = 2048` which is still greater than 1728.  However, encoding all 3 register selectors into one 11-bit field would require much more complex decoding.

A 2-register instruction needs `12^2 = 144` unique register encodings.  But here, `2^(4*2) = 256`, and the next lowest power of 2 (128) isn't big enough.

Probably your best bet is to use 4-bit fields, and use the 13..15 register encodings for something else.  e.g. an escape code that means it's actually a different instruction.  Or if you don't need that much instruction coding space, simplify the decoders and leave your instruction format redundant.

Or really your best bet is to have a power-of-2 number of registers, so you don't waste coding space.  There's a reason that basically every modern register machine has a power-of-2 number of registers.

Answer (score 1):

Registers don't store *"4 digit base 16 numbers"*, that's how you can *interpret* content of such register (seems you mean 16 bit register which when interpreted as hexadecimal integer can store values 0000..FFFF).

But the registers themselves are implemented in HW from bits (0 or 1 value). 16 bit register has 16 bits. Nothing about digits, hexadecimal, etc... those are all features of particular interpretation and interpretation is done either by code using the value in register, or tools used to view content of register.

Anyway, "addressing" register is not relevant in any way to the register content capabilities! The question is to address 12 registers, so for simplicity you can start by giving them names/addresses like 0,1,2,..,11 - how many bits must be reserved to encode that?

How much information can store 1 bit? 0 or 1 = 2 options.

Two bits can store these bit patterns 00, 01, 10, 11 = 4 options.

Three bits can store 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111 = 8 options. (notice, that would you interpret those bits as integer value encoded in binary, I did wrote 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7 ... in that (dis)order ... but when designing CPU you will hardly bother to interpret the register selection bits as integer, it's more like "pattern matching", if register "example1" has pattern 101 inside CPU, then that's how the assembler has to convert source into machine code)

etc...

It's very common to show content of register as hexadecimal values, because then 1 digit is formed by 4 bits, so the programmer debugging the code can easily "see" single bits, if he needs it, but the "hexadecimal number" is only interpretation of the bit pattern stored in register, it's not part of the information encoded. Encoded are only the bit values.

Comment: OP https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/ - if you will toy with this for a while, you will probably decipher that this simple 8 bit machine does use indeed 8 bits for register selection in machine code (allowing theoretically for 256 registers), while it has only 6 registers and flags, so it's wasting many bits in machine code. It would be easy to design machine with same capabilities using 5 bits  for instruction and 3 bits for register selection, producing binaries  of 60-70% size, but the creator did use (for readability?) the simpler 8 bit instruction + 8 bit register.